# Looking for a portable screen for my laptop

Tags: monitors, portable

About 4 or 5 times a year I need to use my laptop while travelling and I would like to carry a second screen.  My current one is an old ASUS thing.  It is fat and has split USB cable, which works only half the time because of its power requirements.

- 15-18 inches
- Light
- Thin, not bulky
- Not too pricey
- Preferably HDMI pluggable into the laptop
- Not a funny dual USB cable for power
- Don't need touch screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up buying this from Amazon

cocopar Portable Travel Monitor 15.6 Inch 1080P FHD USB-C Portable Screen with Dual USB-C Mini HDMI Portable Monitor for Laptop PC Mac Surface Xbox PS5 Switch, with Cover VESA Mountable

[image]